# How can I count the element in specific intervals in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I've got a dataframe like below where columns in c01 represent the start time and c04 the end for time intervals:

```
    c01 c04
1742    8.444991    14.022029
3786    29.91143    31.422439
3951    29.91143    31.145099
5402    37.81136    42.689595
8230    63.12394    65.34602
```

also a list like this (it's actually way longer):

```
8.522494
8.54471
8.578426
8.611193
8.644996
8.678053
8.710918
8.744901
8.777851
8.811053
8.844867
8.878389
8.912099
8.944729
8.977601
9.011232
9.04492
9.078157
9.111946
9.144788
9.177663
9.211054
9.245265
9.27805
9.311766
9.344647
9.377612
9.411709
```

I'd like to count how many elements in the list falls in the intervals shown by the dataframe, where I coded like this:

```
count = 0
for index, row in speech.iterrows():
  count += gtls.count(lambda i : i in [row['c01'], row['c04']])
```

the file works as a whole but all 'count' turns out to be 0, would you please tell me where did I mess up?

Comment: If an element falls into two intervals, should that be counted twice or only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of converting your list into a numpy array() (I called it arr). Then you can use the apply function to create your count column. Let's assume your dataframe is called df.

```
def get_count(row): #the logic for your summation is here
    return np.sum([(row['c01'] < arr) & (row['c04'] >= arr)]) 

df['C_sum'] = df.apply(get_count, axis = 1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
         c01        c04  C_sum
0   8.444991  14.022029     28
1  29.911430  31.422439      0
2  29.911430  31.145099      0
3  37.811360  42.689595      0
4  63.123940  65.346020      0
```

You can also do the whole thing in one line using lambda:

```
df['C_sum'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.sum([(row['c01'] < arr) & (row['c04'] >= arr)]), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! The `i in [row['c01'], row['c04']]` doesn't do what you seem to think; it stands for checking whether element `i` can be found from the two-element list instead of checking the range between `row['c01']` and `row['c04']`. For checking if a floating point number is within a range, use `row['c01'] < i < row['c04']`.